# creating composite index (multiple fields) in mongoDB using java code

Tags: java, mongodb

```
public void createCompositeIndex(MongoClient mongo) {
    Document index = new Document("id_click", 1).append("id_address", 1);
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongo.getDatabase("db").getCollection("Collection");
    collection.createIndex(index, new IndexOptions());
}
```

Comment: Try explaining the problem that you are facing with the posted code.

Comment: @NarendraKatiyar Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 0):

From the [official examples for the MongoDB Java Driver `3.4`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/indexes/):

```
public void createCompositeIndex(MongoClient mongo) {       
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongo
        .getDatabase("db")
        .getCollection("collection");

    collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("field1", "field2"));

    // Or, if you need compound indexes:

   collection.createIndex(Indexes.compoundIndex(
       Indexes.descending("field1"), Indexes.ascending("field2"))
   );
}
```